# Ingreso de datos en diferentes tablas relacionadas. con POO y SQL con una consulta

Tags: php, mysql, poo, objeto

soy nuevo en programación, asi que pido perdón, si estoy preguntando una tontería.
Tengo un formulario en PHP en una pagina PHP de views. el formulario, tendria que ingresar datos en dos tablas que están relacionadas. Eso lo puedo hacer haciendo un ingreso y obteniendo la ultima id antes de hacer la otra entrada.
El tema, es que estoy con mi primer programa en POO y los modelos y controladores que se encargan de hacer las consultas están separados, y el formulario solo puede mandar a uno de los dos para que hagan su trabajo.
Es un poco lioso, espero que me entiendan.
Gracias

Comment: No es una tontería preguntar con el deseo de aprender. Ahora bien, ¿cuál es el problema y en qué código exactamente? Considera que quizá parte de esto debería resolverse a nivel de la base de datos, por ejemplo, programando un disparador (TRIGGER) del tipo  AFTER INSERT que, por cada registro insertado en la tabla A te inserte un nuevo registro en la tabla B, de este modo  evitas tirarle a PHP un problema que debería ser resuelto a nive de base de datos. El TRIGGER se lanzaría de forma transparente y sin intervención del usuario.

Comment: Hola buenas noches, y muchas gracias por responder.

Comment: Hola buenas noches, y muchas gracias por responder. El problema en lenguaje php estructurado, no tengo problema, pero en MVC con POO, al tener una carpeta views, otra controlador, y otra de modelo, se le une, los objetos y dar datos a estos objetos. En fin, tengo una tabla de CLIENTES (id_cliente, nombre, direccion, teléfono, email ) y otra tabla BARCO (id_barco, nombre_barco, puerto, tipo, id_cliente) la relación, llave foranea id_cliente. entonces tengo el formulario que me envía los datos a un controlador, pero mi problema aquí es que tengo dos controladores y dos objetos cliente, y barco.

Comment: Ya, pero eso no es ningún problema... está bien tener tu código organizado. Y si se requiere insertar un cliente y/o un barco, desde el Controlador tú puedes distribuir la información, para que, al recibir los datos, se hagan las inserciones necesarias. ¿Cuál es tu problema concretamente en ese punto? En MVC el Controlador recibiría la información (por ejemplo, el id del cliente, los datos del barco, etc) y te conectaría con el Modelo (en este caso para insertar), recibes de vuelta (en el Controlador) la info de lo que haya ocurrido y lo pasas a la Vista. No hay mayor misterio.

Comment: gracias, mi misterio es que no se si hago bien al tener dos controladores, ClienteControler y BarcoControler con sus respectivos modelos. Mi misterio es que el formulario solo me puede enviar datos a ClienteControler, y BarcoControler, se queda sin datos. Alomejor es porque estoy empezando con POO y MVC y no lo tendría que hacer asi. El formulario tiene los datos del cliente y del barco a la vez, no se como separarlos cada uno para su controlador. De verdad muchisimas gracias por ayudarme.

Comment: Sería interesante que nos digas si usas algún framework tipo Symfony, Laravel u otro ¿? En una aplicación MVC sin frameworks podrías tener un solo controlador en principio y desde allí ir distribuyendo las peticiones. Lo más importante es entender bien el concepto, luego, sobre la marcha, podrás decidir si hay cosas que mejorar, según la complejidad de tu aplicación.

Comment: No utilizo ningun framework, de momento quiero aprender el uso de POO yMVC antes de entrar a otro mundo. Entonces, si entiendo bien puedo hacer un controlador por ej.  DatosControler, que reparta a mis controladores ClienteControler y BarcoControler? Es bastante liado viniendo de aprender programacion estructurada

Comment: Tú puedes efectivamente desde `DatosControler` distribuir a otros controladores o desde ahí mismo puedes conectar tus peticiones con el Modelo según el caso. Para una aplicación sencilla con `DatosController` bastaría. Yo por ejemplo tengo montado un MVC más o menos grande y el controlador es el archivo `index.php` y desde ahí recibo todas las peticiones, conecto con el Modelo según el caso y paso la respuesta a la Vista. Ya, si pasas a Symfony, Laravel u otros podrás perfeccionar, entendiendo cómo funciona MVC desde cero.

Comment: mil gracias, me pongo a ello. No deverías "contestar la pregunta" para tener mas puntos? no se si podre, pero le tendré al corriente de lo que haga en los próximos días, ya que estudio en tiempos libres, y además de tener familia que también necesita tiempo, tengo una pequeña empresa personal que dirigir, y también 49 años. Asi que como es un hobby, tengo que buscarle su tiempo, pero de verdad mil gracias.

Comment: En cuanto al formulario, tú puedes, según el caso, poner una clave cuando el mismo es enviado. Digamos que hay una clave llamada `action`, la cual tendría valores como `cliente`, `barco`, etc. En el Controlador, tú recibes la petición, verificas lo que hay en `action` y si es `cliente` conectas con el Modelo de cliente, si es  `barco` conectas con el modelo de `Barco`, etc. Realmente, en el Controlador no se requiere gran cosa, solamente verificar lo que se está pidiendo o enviando desde el formulario. Otra tarea importante es controlar las peticiones que son permitidas, etc.

Comment: No contesto a la pregunta porque en realidad la misma no plantea un problema concreto. Cuando te pongas a codificar, si tienes algún problema, puedes abrir una nueva pregunta, mostrando la parte de código problemática y entonces sí podrás tener respuestas concretas. En este punto tu pregunta se basa en opiniones y lo mismo que yo te digo todo lo anterior, otro usuario podría decirte que lo hagas de otro modo y así sucesivamente. Conviene por tanto que cuando preguntes nos muestres un contexto mínimo, un código y un problema concreto.

Comment: de verdad muchisimas gracias, y le tendré al corriente si le puedo contestar por esta via. De verdad me ha ayudado con algo que he buscado en internet hasta la saciedad, y nadie dice como hacerlo, asi que me rompí la cabeza buscando la forma como buen auto aprendiz que soy.

Comment: Hola, ya conseguí hacerlo, tras varios intentos, le parecerá una tontería, pero no sabia que en un método de un controlador, puedo crear varios objetos a la vez , darles valores a los campos provenientes del formulario de la vista y llamar a insertarlo en las diferentes tablas. Gracias, por todo, y sigo aprendiendo. Un placer.

Comment: no existen preguntas tontas, existen tontos que no preguntan...

Comment: aclaremos los términos: el formulario de hace en html y se diseña con css, en php se reciben los campos del formulario (inputs); para poder ayudarte con tu problema o duda necesitamos o requerimos ver la estructura de tus bases de datos, si mas no me equivoco lo que están intentando hacer son insert a múltiples tablas o base de datos ... y consultas, creo que debería leer sobre `join` te permite unir tablas al hacer consultas...